# Average in mysql with date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on Averaging several rows of data and I have been busting my butt figuring it out and I "think" Im down to the last error.

```
ERROR 1584 (42000): Incorrect parameters in the call to stored function 'cast'
```

I get this when I run this

```
select avg(volume) from _AAPL WHERE date between cast('2014-02-03' as date) and cast ('2014-05-05'     as DATE);
```

_AAPL is my table, date is my column "date" the dates are already in the database under "date"

I cannot get rid of this error, any ideas?

Comment: The error is due to the white space between the name of the function "`cast`" and the opening paren character "`(`". There are several ways to modify the statement to eliminate the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not have any space after "CAST" :

> cast('2014-05-05'     as DATE)

instead of

```
cast ('2014-05-05'     as DATE)
```

By the way i'm not sure it's mandatory to cast dates when they are already formatted like 'yyyy-mm-dd' : i would just write

```
`column` BETWEEN '2014-02-03' AND '2014-05-05'
```

Comment: +1. "To use the name as a function call in an expression, there must be no whitespace between the name and the following "(" parenthesis character." (unless `SQL_MODE` includes `IGNORE_SPACE`) Ref: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/function-resolution.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/function-resolution.html)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that again to no avail the error is now
    
    ERROR 1064  (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near'2014-02-03 and '2014-0505; at line1

Comment: Could you post your query ?

Comment: select avg(volume) from _AAPL where date between '2014-02-03' and '2014-05-05;

Comment: You have a missing quote after '2014-05-05 : should be select avg(volume) from _AAPL where date between '2014-02-03' and '2014-05-05'

Comment: `column` BETWEEN '2014-02-03' AND '2014-05-05'
yes i my case no need to cast. its works without is as well.

Comment: I wonder why can't they just display an error message which says `You should not have any space after "CAST" `

Answer (score 1):

In [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) you can convert a string literal to a date by using the [`str_to_date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
SELECT AVG(volume) 
FROM   _AAPL 
WHERE  `date` BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE ('2014-02-03', '%Y-%m-%d') AND 
                      STR_TO_DATE ('2014-05-05', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

What for casts are for? It simply works like this:

```
SELECT AVG(volume) FROM _AAPL WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-02-03' AND '2014-05-05';
```